# The term 'direct' in mathematics

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology

On learning some algebra, I had previously stumbled across the term "direct" when considering direct (and inverse) limits. Now Grothendieck in his treatise on topological vector spaces uses the term simply for the image of a function (he refers to the "direct and inverse image" of a function). Unfortunately, I am unable to see the connection between the two concepts, so my question is: Is there any?

Comment: See [Reverse operation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Reverse+operation) : "an operation the steps of which are taken in a contrary order to that in which the same or similar steps are taken in another operation considered as **direct**".

Comment: See [Inverse limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_limit) : "The categorical dual of an *inverse limit* is a *direct limit* (or inductive limit). More general concepts are the limits and colimits of category theory. The terminology is somewhat confusing: inverse limits are limits, while direct limits are colimits."